# How to get ec2 EMR instance from terminating after job complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I want to use the spark-shell after job completes so i dont want my EC2 EMR cluster to stop which it does after it comlpletes the job.

How can i keep the cluster running even thought the job completed?

AWS disable auto terminate?

AWS emr wait ??
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is to add KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Auto-Termination.

You have [cluster termination options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_TerminationProtection.html). Specifically you can provide options at cluster launch time that will prevent the cluster from auto-terminating.

Note that *Termination Protection* and *Auto-Termination* are two different things. The former relates to accidental termination while the latter relates to the transient nature of the cluster.

For more detail, it's worth understanding the [EMR Cluster Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-overview.html#emr-overview-cluster-lifecycle).

Comment: can we do this via AWS cli or cloud formation template?

Comment: Yes (aws emr create-cluster --no-auto-terminate), and yes (AutoTerminate option on Cluster).

Comment: what about, KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps

Comment: That would also work. If you configured your cluster to be long-running (by disabling auto-terminate or by using KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps) then the cluster will go into WAITING state after processing all steps and it will wait for the next set of instructions.